# How to customize $snippet in search results of drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I want to display only node title and node body in search-result.tpl.php. I've configured the display in manage display of content type and hidden all fields except body. However, when I go to search a page, the search result displays language + body.

example: the content of $snippet is "English content of the body." With the "English" is a language and "content of the body" is a node body. I don't know why it displayed language in search result page.

My site is two languages English and Vietnamese. When I search in English language, the search result is display "Tiếng việt Content of the body." When I search in Vietnamese language, the search result is display "English content of the body."

How can I delete language "English" or "Tiếng Việt" before node body in search result?

You can see on this test site.

http://nepivn.wiwisol.com/en/search/node/content
http://nepivn.wiwisol.com/vi/search/node/mi%C3%AAu%20t%E1%BA%A3

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you fixed this... since this issue is almost 2 years old but I found the "Hide translation links" setting on this page: admin/config/regional/i18n/node. Since I wanted to hide the translation links everywhere and not just the Search results, I'm not sure if this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a solution for the last 48 hours.